# Replacing values on a database using R

Tags: sql, r

I'm currently learning how to use R to manipulate large databases. My current task, is to find a value in a column and replace it with the name of the clinic that's associated with that number.

```
library(RODBC)
library(odbc)
library(dplyr)

## Establishing connection with db
diag<- "bases de prueba/DIAGNOSTICO 22.MDB"
con <- RODBC::odbcConnectAccess2007(diag)


##Check conection content
RODBC::sqlTables(con)


## Fetch table
tabla<-sqlFetch(con,'tres', rownames=FALSE)


updatequery <- paste("update tres set centro = " ,111, " where centro = 1")
## Updates value 1 in column "centro" to 111. 
## Actually, in this case I'll need to change it to "centro 1", ...
## ... but i get "centro 1 object not found" error. 

RODBC::sqlQuery(con,updatequery)
## When i run this line of code i get an error along the lines of ...
## ... "data types of the criteria doesnt match".
```

Comment: is `centro` a character column?  Perhaps you need additional single quotes around the values of centro, like this:  `paste0("update tres set centro = '" ,111, "' where centro = '1'")

Comment: @langtang that worked! Thank you very much.
Now when I change "111" to "Centro 1", i get the following message:
[1] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'update tres set centro = ' Centro 1 ' where centro = '1''"
Any idea how to fix this?
 Oh and yes, "centro" is indeed a character column.

Comment: Maybe the data type is character of a fixed length less than 8? If that is the case, trying to update row(s) to “Centro 1” could lead to truncation, because the new value requires 8 characters

Comment: @langtang the column is set as "short text", and i've also tried "centro1", same result.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: maybe you already changed all the values to 111, and so there aren't any values with '1' anymore?  hard to tell without more information

Comment: @langtang Yup, that was certainly the case, (facepalm emoji).
Is there any synthax to run this line of code for other clinics at once? 2 to centro 2, 3 to x, etc...
Thanks again, you've been very helpfull!